# Sheet JS using spaces in excel file headers

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, excel, sheetjs

I'm using SheetJS to parse out an externally linked excel spreadsheet and create some HTML elements.

Overall, the way that I have it set up is fine, but I noticed that if the excel sheet that I'm referencing has spaces in the header (e.g. - First Name, Last Name, etc.) it won't recognize that and errors out. And I'm not sure how to go about accommodating the spaces in the headers.

Here's what I have:

**Excel File Data:**
[image]

**JS:**

```
var url = "https://assets.codepen.io/8689/test2.xlsx";

/* set up XMLHttpRequest */

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", url, true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

oReq.onload = function (e) {
  var arraybuffer = oReq.response;

  /* convert data to binary string */
  var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
  var arr = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
  var bstr = arr.join("");

  /* Call XLSX */
  var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });

  /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
  var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
  /* Get worksheet */
  var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];

  var jData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { raw: false });

  $.each(jData, function (i, f) {
    var el =
      "<div class='thing'>" +
      "<h2>" +
      f.First Name +
      "&nbsp;" +
      f.Last Name +
      "</h2>" +
      "<h3>" +
      f.Title +
      "</h3>" +
      "<p>" +
      f.Comment +
      "</p>" +
      "</div>";
    $(el).appendTo("#wrapper");
  });

  console.log(jData);
};

oReq.send();
```

I know that `f.First Name` and `f.Last Name` will error out, and I'm not sure what I can do to try and get it to accommodate the space. I tried an underscore, but that obviously doesn't work either (I kind of figured, but I wanted to test to be sure).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did some more digging and I realized that since this is JSON data that is being parsed, I can use bracket notation to help parse that out:

```
$.each(jData, function (i, f) {
    var el =
      "<div class='thing'>" +
      "<h2>" +
      f["First Name"] +
      "&nbsp;" +
      f["Last Name"] +
      "</h2>" +
      "<h3>" +
      f.Title +
      "</h3>" +
      "<p>" +
      f.Comment +
      "</p>" +
      "</div>";
  });
```